# вывести цифры из строки

Tags: java, строки

есть строка в которой есть цифры
строка1: nnnnnnn4012
результат должен быть: 4012

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать это регулярное выражение:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```